# Google Sheet Trigger Script on FormSubmit - Triggers Says "The Selected Function Cannot Be Found"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need my Google Sheet to automatically sort entries from a form when they come in. The script works...with the exception of triggering automatically when the entry comes in. Kind of the most important part! I'm getting an error that says "The Selected Function Cannot Be Found" (screenshot below).

Here's the code I'm using in the Script:

```
function onSubmit(){ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:Z");

  range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: true},  {column: 4, ascending: true}, {column:3, ascending: true}]);

 }
```

[image: Error Message]

So where am I messing up??

Comment: Maybe I'm reading this wrong, but the function you have there is named `onSubmit`, not `onFormSubmit` (which is what's in the dialog box). Is that the issue?

Comment: I've tried both onSubmit and onFormSubmit and get the error message either way, unfortunately!

I've tried onSubmit, onFormSubmit, and onEdit

Answer (score 0):

For installable triggers, don't name your functions onSomething to avoid confusion with simple triggers. Choose a normal, descriptive name that reflects what the function does.

Delete any installable triggers that complain about function not being found.

Create a new installable trigger, using the name of the function chosen above. Do not rename the function from now on.